# I'm having problems to round to two digits plain calculation in pyspark in DataBricks

Tags: pyspark, rounding, databricks

I'm getting the following error: It shows the following error: Invalid argument, not a string or column: `1586906.0151878505` of type `<class 'float'>`. For column literals, use `'lit'`, `'array'`, `'struct'` or `'create_map'` function.

the code goes something like this

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

population= int(df.count())

income_sum= int(df.agg(_sum('income_job1')).collect()[0][0])

Tot_mean_income = round(income_sum/population,2)
```

Comment: Can you please include some input and expected output in tabular format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are having **`conflict`** issues with **`round`** function in **`pyspark.sql.functions`** package with regular python **`round`** function.

Try with importing functions with **`alias`** so that there will be no conflict with **`round`** function.

```
#import functions with alias
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *
df=spark.createDataFrame([(1,'a'),(2,'b')],['id','name'])
population=int(df.count())
income_sum=int(df.agg(F.sum(F.col("id"))).collect()[0][0])
Tot_mean_income = round(income_sum/population,2)
#1.5
```

Comment: yes... that seems to be the issue... thanks a lot!!!